# Custom wordpress preloader with CSS and javascript

Tags: wordpress

I want to make my own custom preloader with javascript and CSS but I don't have idea from where to start. I mean how to calculate loading percentage in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show preloader only on page load

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    $('.preloader').addClass('hide');
});
```

And yourcss

```
.preloader {
    /* your styles */
}

.hide {
    /* your styles */
    display: none;   
}
```

Or If you want to show percentage on load you can look at this plugin: https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/